# Reload view on param change

Tags: angularjs

For some reason neither controller nor view is not reloaded when I change URL parameter. What I did is opened **/events/1** then opened **/events/2** and expected the **currentDate** updated but it doesn't :(

My state config:

```
.state('events', {
    url: "/events",
    controller: 'EventsCtrl',
    templateUrl: "Content/Directives/Navigator/navigator.html",
})
.state('events.event', {
    url: "/{id:int}",
    reload: true,
    template: '{{currentDate}}'
});
```

My controller:

```
function NavigatorCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.currentDate = new Date();
}
```

navigator.html:

```
<div class="row">
    <h3>Navigator</h3>
    <ui-view/>
</div>
```

Why it is not updated? How can I force state to update view on every URL parameter change?
Notice, I wrote "reload: true" but it probably has no effect because it's normally used in options when calling state.go().
ps: I know I can convert this "$scope.currentDate = new Date();" to a function but wondering if described behaviuor is normal...

Comment: I think you should use url:"/events/{id:int}"

Comment: @Gerfried the dot in state name already makes it a child of `events`

Comment: Seem to be missing `controller` for `events.event` state. Not clear where `NavigatorCtrl` is being clled

Comment: @charlietfl as far as I understood from the docs it is not necessary and it doesnt report errors rendering template correctly.. Weird thihg that it does not refresh on every second URL change.

Comment: @LINQ2Vodka the parent state won't refresh. If that date was in controller registered to the child view it would however create new instance

Comment: @charlietfl is there a way to configure state so it forces refresh anyway? So I could add thsoption to the parent Ctrl

Comment: probably is... i haven't ever needed to use it so would need to dig through the docs

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for a location change, and reload your controller once it will trigger.

```
   $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
       $state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, { reload: true, inherit: true, notify: true });
   });
```

Should works, but I did not test it in plunker. If you could provide me plunker of your app I can finish your example. Hope, it will help you!